# What are the names of network interfaces on the Motorola CLIQ XT?

Tags: android, motorola, clique

The network interfaces on Android interfaces are listed as directories in the file system in **/sys/class/net/**.

For most Android devices the network interface for gprs traffic is called **rmnet0** and for Wi-Fi it's usually **eth0** or **tiwlan0**.

I suspect that the cell interface for the Motorola CLIQ XT is **rmnet0**, but I would like to have this confirmed + know the name of the Wi-Fi interface.

Also it would be good to know the device id for this model. This is the value available as **android.os.Build.DEVICE** in the Java SDK. (E.g. T-Mobile G1 uses *dream*, Samsung Galaxy uses *GT-I7500*, and Motorolda Droid uses *sholes*.)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the **Motorola CLIQ XT (Zeppelin/MB501)** running Android 1.5 has a cell network interface called **rmnet0** and a Wi-Fi network interface called **eth0**. The device's id is **zeppelin**.